# Postgresql: Connection refused on port 5432

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I'm stuck with a self-inflicted error I'm unable to solve. I made a change to PostgreSQL 13 Connections and Authentication, changing the port from 5432 to 5433. After that, I got psql error 'could not connect to server' (see image for more details). I've tried to connect via pgAdmin, but that resulted in the same error. So I reverted what I've done to the original 5432 and restarted psql, but the error remained.

I want to connect to the default 5432 port again, but I can't get around this issue. Can someone explain to me how to fix this issue? I'm running Windows 10 on my machine if that matters.

Here's a psql error:

[image: PSQL error]

And here's what I got with pgAdmin 4:

[image: pgAdmin4 error]

**EDIT:**

In services.msc I've found that the server is not running. I've tried to start the server, but all I got is "PostgreSQL Server 13 service on Local Computer started and then stopped ..." (check screenshot for more info). I have tried to start it again, even to change Startup type (Automatic, Manual, etc.), but the message is still the same.
[image: posgresql-server]

Comment: Use `psql -p 5433 -U ...`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. I've tried that, actually. I've added a new server to that port with pgAdmin. But I actually want to connect back to 5432, and I can't figure out how.

Comment: Is your serveur configured on port 5432 ?

Comment: Please describe how exactly you changed the port to 5433.

Comment: @Philippe >> Yes, the server is configured on port 5432.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe >> I have manually edited postgresql.conf file (Connections and Authentication), changing port 5432 to 5433.

Comment: Well, then change it back and restart the PostgreSQL server.

Comment: Look in the PostgreSQL server's log file.  This will tell you if it failed to start, or if it succeeded but not on the port you expected.

Comment: Also check the eventlog of windows. If the postgresql service can't be started, there should be some info there.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe >> I did just that, as I stated in the original post. The error remains the same.

Comment: I see. What error messages do you find in the PostgreSQL log?

Comment: Guys, I have reinstalled PostgreSQL. I know it's not the best practice, but it works now. Thank you all for your help!